# OpenCV: Combine/Merge overlapping boundary boxes, replace by surrounding boundary box

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

i'm working on comparing bounding boxes and combining boxes that overlap too much. I got it working with this code from another post:

```
def non_max_suppression_fast(boxes, overlapThresh):
   # if there are no boxes, return an empty list
   if len(boxes) == 0:
      return []

   # if the bounding boxes integers, convert them to floats --
   # this is important since we'll be doing a bunch of divisions
   if boxes.dtype.kind == "i":
      boxes = boxes.astype("float")
#  
   # initialize the list of picked indexes   
   pick = []

   # grab the coordinates of the bounding boxes
   x1 = boxes[:,0]
   y1 = boxes[:,1]
   x2 = boxes[:,2]
   y2 = boxes[:,3]

   # compute the area of the bounding boxes and sort the bounding
   # boxes by the bottom-right y-coordinate of the bounding box
   area = (x2 - x1 + 1) * (y2 - y1 + 1)
   idxs = np.argsort(y2)

   # keep looping while some indexes still remain in the indexes
   # list
   while len(idxs) > 0:
      # grab the last index in the indexes list and add the
      # index value to the list of picked indexes
      last = len(idxs) - 1
      i = idxs[last]
      pick.append(i)

      # find the largest (x, y) coordinates for the start of
      # the bounding box and the smallest (x, y) coordinates
      # for the end of the bounding box
      xx1 = np.maximum(x1[i], x1[idxs[:last]])
      yy1 = np.maximum(y1[i], y1[idxs[:last]])
      xx2 = np.minimum(x2[i], x2[idxs[:last]])
      yy2 = np.minimum(y2[i], y2[idxs[:last]])

      # compute the width and height of the bounding box
      w = np.maximum(0, xx2 - xx1 + 1)
      h = np.maximum(0, yy2 - yy1 + 1)

      # compute the ratio of overlap
      overlap = (w * h) / area[idxs[:last]]

      # delete all indexes from the index list that have
      idxs = np.delete(idxs, np.concatenate(([last],
         np.where(overlap > overlapThresh)[0])))

   # return only the bounding boxes that were picked using the
   # integer data type
   return boxes[pick].astype("int")
```

How can I modify this code to replace both overlapping boxes by a rectangle that surrounds both boundary boxes? This code only deletes one of the boxes and keeps the other one.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for area. The bounding rectangle is the minima/maxima of the coordinate points. If we assume `x1 < x2` and `y1 < y2` then we can use the min among all `x1` as the bounding box `x1`, min among `y1` as bounding box `y1`, and similarly max among all `x2`, `y2` for bounding box `x2`,`y2` respectively.

For more complex bounding shapes look into convex hull algorithms.

Comment: Thanks. Yes that makes sense. But I honestly don't know how to edit the definition for idxs in order to save the resulting boxes instead of just deleting some boxes. I'm not as good with python and I'm not exactly sure how to handlle those lists etc. Can you give me a hint how I need to edit that function? Also, I edited the definition of overlap to "max((w * h) / area[idxs[:last]], (w * h) / area[i]), so the overlap is compared to both the bigger and the smaller box. It doesn't make sense to me to just compare it to one of the boxes.